# Is float assignment counted as using fpu?

Tags: linux, context-switch, fpu

Since fpu operation is very costly, I would like to less use fpu operations as far as I can. In the meanwhile, I'm wondering what kind of operations within the float variable would counted as the operation that fpu involves?

Such as the following code would involve fpu unit?

```
struct my_float_struct {
    int f;
} g;

void func(float a)
{
    g.f = a;
}
```

would calling func will cause lazy FPU context switch?

Comment: Probably not, but it depends on the hardware.

Comment: i don't believe float operation is available in kernel

Comment: It depends. If `g` was stored on a FPU register then obviously FPU will be used.

Answer (score 0):

In kernel you shouldn't use `float` at all (use [lookup tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookup_table) and multiplying by coefficients to save precision on divide operations instead). In user space all operations involving `float` type on RHS would lead to FPU instruction usage. If you have 2 integers on RHS but assigning result to float (on LHS) -- you will end up with integer operations, but also with casting to float instruction (like 
`cvtsi2ss`).

It's actually very easy to answer your question just looking into disassemble for corresponding C code.

C code (build with `gcc -Wall -O0 -g main.c`):

```c
int main(void)
{
    volatile float f1, f2;
    volatile int i;

    f1 = i * 356;
    f2 = f1 * f2;

    return 0;
}
```

Disassemble (using `objdump -DS a.out`):

```
int main(void)
{
  4004b6:       55                      push   %rbp
  4004b7:       48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
        volatile float f1, f2;
        volatile int i;

        f1 = i * 356;
  4004ba:       8b 45 f4                mov    -0xc(%rbp),%eax
  4004bd:       69 c0 64 01 00 00       imul   $0x164,%eax,%eax
  4004c3:       66 0f ef d2             pxor   %xmm2,%xmm2
  4004c7:       f3 0f 2a d0             cvtsi2ss %eax,%xmm2
  4004cb:       66 0f 7e d0             movd   %xmm2,%eax
  4004cf:       89 45 fc                mov    %eax,-0x4(%rbp)
        f2 = f1 * f2;
  4004d2:       f3 0f 10 4d fc          movss  -0x4(%rbp),%xmm1
  4004d7:       f3 0f 10 45 f8          movss  -0x8(%rbp),%xmm0
  4004dc:       f3 0f 59 c8             mulss  %xmm0,%xmm1
  4004e0:       66 0f 7e c8             movd   %xmm1,%eax
  4004e4:       89 45 f8                mov    %eax,-0x8(%rbp)

        return 0;
  4004e7:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
}
```

From here you can see that:

- when multiplying integer by integer, but assigning result to float, it leads to [imul](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_138.html) instruction (integer multiplying), but also to [cvtsi2ss](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_59.html) (converting to float) instruction.
- when multiplying 2 floats, it leads to [mulss](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_214.html) instruction, which float multiplying

Basically you can see immediately if FPU involved by instruction operates on FPU registers, like `%xmm0`, `%xmm1`, etc.